# Como insertar una web mediante un IFRAME, pero no se deja por seguridad

Tags: html, jquery, iframe

Buenasamigos como estan? tengo un problema con una app web que estoy desarrollando, y pues necesito entregarla hoy! sin embargo un simple IFRAM me esta dando dolores de cabeza...

Sucede que la web funciona para ver computadores de los trabajadores de la empresa mediante https://www.dwservice.net/ que proporciona este servicio... ahora, se supone que al yo dar click en alguno de los iconos de las computadoras me deberia resultar un iframe con una la web correspondiente
.. sin embargo, tengo problemas, ya que la web no me deja insertar contenido por seguridad, y al parecer no aportan apis... es decir un total desastre... Intente hacerlo mediante un Popup, pero el cliente requiere que no se vea el enlace, y pues imposible a estas fechas hacer eso... esta realmente dificil, muy muy dificil...

Ya intente con , ya intente con Jquery cargando el contenido a un Object, ya intente con los pop ups, ya intente todo!!!!! de verdad que ya no se que hacer para mostrar dicha web en en panel que estoy desarrollando, intente montarla mediante todo lo habido y por havber, y llevo horas.. HORAS EN ESTO!... y pues mi cerebro ya de verdad que no me da.

la web que estoy desarrollando es esta: i-codes.online. y se supone que en ver enlaces, debo de poder agregar los enlaces de las maquinas en un iframe... cosa que me impide la misma web original.
De antemano muchas gracias,

PD. disculpen si rompi alguna(s) reglas... En mis 6 años programando es primera vez que uso Stackoverflow para realizar una pregunte jeje...

Comment: Me suena a que estas intentando incluir la web de un tercero en tu propio sitio web, si es así, seguramente el mensaje dice algo de same-origin, lo único que puedes hacer es llamar al equipo de desarrollo de dicho sitio y pedir que te incluyan en su política de seguridad para permitirte usar iframe

Comment: La respuesta sencilla es: no podrás cargar la web de un tercero en un `iframe` si las políticas de seguridad de ese tercero no te lo permiten. No le des más vuelta al asunto y averigua con ese tercero si te permiten el uso de `iframes` para tu propio dominio. De lo contrario no hay nada que puedas hacer. Saludos

Comment: Lo que sucede es que necesito mostrar el contenido de una web, sin mostrar el el enlace de origen, intente hacerlo con windows.open() como ya habia comentado,pero me muestra el enlace, y ya no se puedeocltar con las propiedades de dicha funcion, algunaidea decomo puedo mostrar la informacion de esa web sin necesidad ver lo que es la url.. ocultarla

Answer (score -2):

Por lo que tengo entendido para mostrar un `iframe` de una web, esta debe de tener el dominio seguro **(https)** Intenta añadirle un certificado SSL y vuelve a intentarlo, debería de funcionar. Un saludo y espero que te sirva

Comment: Esto no responde la pregunta, es sólo un comentario. Te invito a repasar [answer]. Mi sugerencia es que borres esta publicación y lo dejes como un simple comentario. Por cierto, ni usando toda la seguridad del mundo podrás cargar la web de un tercero en un `iframe` de tu propia web si así lo establecen las políticas de seguridad de la web de dicho tercero. Saludos

Comment: me temo que no funciona de esa manera, mientras la web de destino tenga CORS es imposible traermela mediante un iframe. aunque gracias por la recomendacion